# Java - Use main method of a package in another class

Tags: java, import, package, program-entry-point

Let's say I have a package called `com.Gazzali` and  inside this package I've 3 another classes.

```
package com.Gazzali;
//Driver class
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hey There !");
    FireCall target = new FireCall(); // calls 2nd class (named: Firecall)
    target.callfired();
 }
}
```

2nd class:

```
package com.Gazzali;

public class FireCall {
   public void callfired()
   {
    System.out.println("Calling function Triggered.");
    Execute Fire = new Execute(); //calls 3rd class (named : Execution).
    if(Fire.click() == 1)
        System.out.println("You're Dead, Boy !!!");
    else
        System.out.println("Whoooss Saved !!!");
    }
 }
```

3rd class:

```
package com.Gazzali;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Execute {
int choice;
Scanner query = new Scanner(System.in);

public int click()
{
    System.out.println("Enter a choice : ");
    choice = query.nextInt();
    if(choice % 2 == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
}
```

these 3 comprises my `com.Gazzali` package. Now in another file (`RunPackTest.java`) I want to call the `main` method of `Main` class (Driver class). So I tried importing like below:

```
import com.Gazzali.Main;
public class RunPackTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main run = new Main(); //calling Main method of Driver class of the package 
    System.out.println(run); //Doesn't seem to work,IDE only return 0 
}

}
```

How to do this? beacuse the `main` method of `Main` class starts the program and calls another classess of the package accordingly.

Comment: `new Main()` just create a new instance but doesn't do anything else. Either call `run.main(args)` or (better) provide a method that actually contains the logic and call that from both `main()` methods.

Comment: Exactly: it is bad practice to invoke another main method.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you're confusing classes with methods; are you sure you need to create a whole new class to just implement one method within them?

Comment: @Thomas , Thanks now it's working !

Comment: @Zephyr , Yash , I'm beginner in Java. I was doing a self practice on `package` like the C++ OOP calling methods.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would do it:

```
import com.Gazzali.Main;

public class RunPackTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.main(null);
    }
}
```

You can call `main` just like any other method, although it's not good practice in general.